# Implementing exponential backoff in spark between consecutive attempts

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

On our AWS EMR spark cluster we have 100-150 jobs running at a given time. Each cluster-task-node is allocated 7 of 8 cores. But at some hour in a day the load average touches 10 --causing task failure/ task lost/ executors lost/ heart beat missed. If we decrease the allocated cores/node the cluster is under utilised (load avg 4)

To avoid executors lost/ tasks lost --we tried increasing maxAttempts, but all the attempts are happening in that hour window only and the job is failing.

So, as intermediary we are thinking of

1. having try catch in the main method. So that executor lost, max attempts exceeded exceptions can be caught and... re-trigger the code
2. The EMR-core-nodes have 6 of 8cores allocated to spark --May be for this reason the driver never crashed!

So the questions

1. Will re-triggering main code in the same JVM several times any side affects? It can happen that there are some dataframes already created in the previous run and now they are getting recreated. Or recached or the SQL is getting re-executed
2. if this is not the way then any suggestions on how to get exponential backoff?

we are using spark 3.3 on AWS EMR 6.X. The spark job is triggered via sh file.

Comment: Can you see the stacktrace of the executor?

Comment: i see this `Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 372 in stage 6.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure:`  -->  stage i think is executor and the above is executor stack trace which also has driver stack trace below it `Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2863)`

Comment: But the cause of the error of the task. Normally it can be caused by a OutOfMemory error and if you have access to the stage via the driver console you can see the error there.

Comment: Yes OOM is possible. But the question is for the case where its not OOM. For OOM The strategy said above will comeout with out retry -- which is better, while `maxAttemts` of spark Job retries the job inspite of OOM.